# HTML canvas : how to create a polygon filled with a grid

Tags: html, canvas

I order to build a HTML 5 datacenter floor plan, I would like to create a polygon filled with a grid. This grid must not be a picture pattern as I would like to be able to zoom or rotate the floor plan without having pixelization.
I would like to be able to create this kind of output :

[image]

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways, like

- using a [clipping region](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip)

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
drawShape();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.save(); // so we can remove the clipping
ctx.clip();
drawGrid();
ctx.restore(); // remove the clipping

function drawShape() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  var pts = [
    20, 20,
    80, 20,
    90, 50,
    120, 90,
    30, 80,
    20,20
  ];
  for(var i=0;i<pts.length;i+=2){
    ctx.lineTo(pts[i], pts[i+1]);
  }
}
function drawGrid() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var x=-.5; x<c.width; x+=20) {
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, c.height);
  }
  for(var y=-.5; y<c.height; y+=20) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(c.width, y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

- using [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
drawGrid();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
drawShape();
ctx.fill();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
ctx.stroke();

function drawShape() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  var pts = [
    20, 20,
    80, 20,
    90, 50,
    120, 90,
    30, 80,
    20,20
  ];
  for(var i=0;i<pts.length;i+=2){
    ctx.lineTo(pts[i], pts[i+1]);
  }
}
function drawGrid() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var x=-.5; x<c.width; x+=20) {
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, c.height);
  }
  for(var y=-.5; y<c.height; y+=20) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(c.width, y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

But in your case, a regular grid, it might actually be better to use a pattern.

Indeed, you'd have to only draw one cell every time you change the scale of your grid, for translations, this can be done internally.
So I didn't do the performance tests myself, and thus encourage you to double check it's worth it, but theoretically, it might be faster and esaier to manage than redrawing the grid every time.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var pat_ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
var cell_size = 20;

// just a basic drawing example
// first we generate the grid as a pattern
ctx.fillStyle = generatePattern(cell_size, cell_size);
drawShape();
ctx.stroke();
// we move the pattern by half a cell because we actually drawn only a cross
ctx.translate(-cell_size / 2, -cell_size / 2);
ctx.fill();


// make the grid follow the mouse
// without having to redraw ourself the grid
onmousemove = function(e) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  drawShape();
  ctx.stroke();
  // move the grid
  ctx.translate(e.clientX - cell_size / 2, e.clientY - -cell_size / 2);
  ctx.fill();
}
// click to zoom (+shift to zoom out)
onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey) cell_size--;
  else cell_size++;
  ctx.fillStyle = generatePattern(cell_size, cell_size);
  onmousemove(e);
}
// dimply draws a cross
function generatePattern(w, h) {
  var canvas = pat_ctx.canvas;
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  pat_ctx.moveTo(w / 2, 0);
  pat_ctx.lineTo(w / 2, h);
  pat_ctx.moveTo(0, h / 2);
  pat_ctx.lineTo(w, h / 2);
  pat_ctx.stroke();
  return pat_ctx.createPattern(canvas, 'repeat');
}

function drawShape() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  var pts = [
    20, 20,
    80, 20,
    90, 50,
    120, 90,
    30, 80,
    20, 20
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < pts.length; i += 2) {
    ctx.lineTo(pts[i], pts[i + 1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know it was possible this way.